# Continuity of a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I was doing some self studying and came across this question I'm having difficulties with:

Let $D = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: 0≤x≤1,\; y≥x\}\cup\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:−1≤x≤1, \;y=x\}$,

$E=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:−1≤x≤1,\; y=x\}$.

Define $f: D\rightarrow E$ by $f(x,y) = (x,x)$. Is $f$ continuous, and can we prove if it is a closed or an open map?

I've worked with proving continuity for functions that map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ before, and now working in two dimensions is a bit confusing.

Comment: I would say that it is both continuous and on open map. I would suggest trying to visualise the mapping geometrically. It is basically a vertical projection on the line (x, x)

Comment: @chess4ever to be honest I find this quite hard to visualise; you have to somehow see a subset of $\mathbb{R} ^2$ collapse to a line in $\mathbb{R} ^2$, so I am not sure how we can think of it as a vertical projection

Comment: Please do not delete questions after getting an answer.  This is disrespectful to the person who took the time to write that answer.

Comment: Especially if the answer is quite comprehensive and obviously took lots of effort.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Why is it possible to delete good questions after a good answer?

Answer (score 3):

Before presenting the proofs, we should remember that when we want to speak about continuity, we need the appropriate 'context'. This context is given by either some notion of distance (a metric), or by some available topology. When we deal with one dimension, we almost take for granted that we are using a metric, namely the modulus that appears in the epsilon-delta definition of continuity! But we are actually not restricted to just one metric or topology, and hence the property of whether or not a function is continuous is very much dependent on the 'context'. In the case of $\mathbb{R}^2$, it is quite common that we defer to the standard topology, or the euclidean metric, which is what I do here. But I think it's important to remember that these assumptions matter, and that they are just assumptions! (At least this is very helpful for me!)

**Proof of continuity**

To prove the function is continuous, let's first treat $D$ and $E$  as subspaces of the metric space $\mathbb{R}^2$. We will assume $\mathbb{R}^2$ has the standard euclidean metric (and this is just an assumption, if you change the metric, you may change the situation!). So now we are to prove the function $f$ between the metric spaces $(D,d_2|_D) $ and $(E, d_2|_E)$ is continuous. These metrics are simply the restriction of the euclidean metric to $D$ and $E$. First we note the definition of continuity of a point between metric spaces:

We say the function $f$ is continuous at the point $a$ in $D$ if $$\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists\delta>0 \text{ s.t. whenever }x\in D \text{ and } d(x,a) < \delta, \text{ then, } d'(f(x),f(a)) < \epsilon$$

Now we prove your given function $f$ is continuous. Suppose $a = (a_1,a_2) \in D$ and suppose $\epsilon > 0$. Now let $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}}$. Suppose now that $x = (x_1,x_2) \in D$ and $d_2|_D (x,a) < \delta$. Then we have $$\sqrt{(a_1 - x_1)^2 + (a_2 - x_2)^2} < \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}}$$ But this means $$(a_1 - x_1)^2 + (a_2 - x_2)^2 < \frac{\epsilon ^2}{2}$$ Since $(a_2 - x_2)^2$ is necessarily positive, we have $$(a_1 - x_1)^2 < \frac{\epsilon ^2}{2}$$

and thus $$2(a_1 - x_1)^2 = (a_1 - x_1)^2 + (a_1 - x_1)^2< \epsilon^2$$ But notice that this is nothing but $$d_2|_E (f(x),f(a)) < \epsilon$$ Hence $f$ is continuous. (Here we note that the proof shows continuity because we assumed $a\in D$ to be arbitrary, and hence we have continuity everywhere in D.)

**Proof that $f$ is not an open map**

Now we show that $f$ is not an open map. To do this, I will assume $D$ and $E$ take the subspace topology, with respect to the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$. I think it will be very helpful to draw an image of what the sets $D$ and $E$ look like to aid with visualisation.

We define the set $S = D\setminus E$, and note that it is open in the subspace topology of $D$. To see why the set $S$ is open, we note that for every point in $x \in S$, there exists an open ball $B_d(x,\epsilon)$ with $\epsilon$ sufficiently small such that $\big(D \cap B_d(x,\epsilon)\big) \subset S$ (for example, take $\epsilon$ to be any value greater than $0$ and less than the perpendicular euclidean distance to the line $y=x$ with domain $0 \leq x \leq 1$). All open balls are open in the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$, and thus $D \cap B_d(x,\epsilon)$ is an open set in $D$ (by definition of the subspace topology), contained in $S$. The union of all such sets for every point in $S$ is equal to $S$ itself. Thus $S$ is open in the subspace topology $D$.

Now we consider the image of $S$. $$\begin{align} f(S) & = \{f(x,y) \in E: (x,y) \in S\} \\ & = \{(x,x) \in E: x\in [0,1] \}\end{align}$$ In other words, the set $S$ is the line $y=x$ from $0$ to $1$, *inclusive*. But lines are closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and hence $f(S)$ is closed in the subspace topology $E$ (the conclusion here makes use of [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Closed_Set_in_Topological_Subspace) theorem). But in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the only simultaneously closed and open sets are $\mathbb{R}^2$ itself and $\emptyset$. Thus $f(S)$ is not open. Therefore the image of the open set $S$ is not open, and hence the map $f$ is not an open mapping.

Comment: Hi @masiewpao! If $f$ is not an open map, is $f$ a closed map in this case? And can we say anything about a quotient map maybe?

Comment: @MathStudentie where exactly are you getting stuck in your attempts to prove these things? Also remember, open and closed maps are NOT converse properties!

Comment: @masiewpao you are saying that $f(S)$ is closed (and not open) in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but shouldn't we consider the subspace topology on $E$?

Comment: @chess4ever $f(S)$ is indeed closed in the subspace topology of $E$. The reason we can conclude that however is because the line $y=x$ from $0$ to $1$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (the intersection of that line with $E$ is simply the line itself)

Comment: You are right, but stated that way it could be a little bit misleading, because to prove that $f$ is not an open map, you have to prove that $f(S)$ is not open (and the fact that it is closed is not enough). We have to say that $f(S)$ is not open in the subspace topology due to the point $(0,0)$. In fact $(1,1)$ is actually not a problem here.

Comment: @chess4ever Ah yes, I see your point; I should mention that in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the only clopen sets are the trivial ones. I'll edit to make it clearer because it does currently give the impression they are converse properties.